# Palindrome of List in Haskell with Higher-Order functions

Tags: haskell

This is my code to check if a list is a palindrome:

```
isPalindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool

isPalindrome []  = True
isPalindrome [_] = True
isPalindrome xs  = (head xs == last xs) && (isPalindrome (tail (init xs)))
```

Is it possible to do this by using higher-order functions in Haskell?

Comment: Maybe I completely miss it, but what is wrong with `reverse xs == xs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `foldr` + `zipWith` combination:

```
isPalindrome xs = foldr (&&) True $ zipWith (==) xs (reverse xs)
```

- `zipWith (==) xs (reverse xs)` produces a `[Bool]` list: in case of palindrome it will contain only `True` values
- `foldr (&&) True` will use the result of `zipWith` function to test if all values are `True`

It can be also simplified to:

```
isPalindrome xs = and $ zipWith (==) xs (reverse xs)
```

In GHCi:

```
Prelude> isPalindrome [1,2,1]
True
Prelude> isPalindrome [1,2,1,1]
False
Prelude> isPalindrome "salas"
True
Prelude> isPalindrome "salsa"
False
```

Comment: Thanks very much! How are foldr and zipwith working together for this example?

Comment: N.B. `foldr (&&) True == all id`

Comment: @blazing `foldr` function uses a result from `zipWith` as an input. Both functions are higher order functions: they take function as an argument (`(&&)` in case of `foldr` and `(==)` in case of `zipWith`) and they can return a function thanks to currying. `foldr (&&) True` can be even replaced by `and` function, because folding right a list of `[Bool]` type using `&&` is what `and` function does.

Comment: But why do you produce a boolean list, are you comparing the reverse list with the input list: [a,b,b,a] and [a,b,b,a] and storing [True,True,True,True], and then if the list contains all True's then it is a palindrome?

Comment: Correct. `zipWith` zips elements from `xs` and `reverse xs`, applies `(==)` function on each pair and creates `[Bool]` list as a result. It evaluates to `True` if all elements are `True` (`foldr (&&) True xs` or `and xs`). It's a lot if we compare it with the simplest (I guess) possible version `isPalindrome xs = xs == reverse xs`, but I thought that you were looking for an alternative to recursive approach.

Comment: I was looking for an alternative recursive approach, Thanks very much!

Comment: There’s also a cute point-free version of the non-recursive definition: `isPalindrome = (==) <*> reverse`